# For a T-test, what would happen if one of my samples was made up of only one observation?

Tags: t-test, small-sample

I must be missing something, or under-thinking what goes on with a basic T Test, but I was under the impression that if I do a T-test, and one of my samples was made up of only one observation, the test would fail.

To see if this is indeed the case, I ran some code in Python code.  I made up some numbers, where my first sample has 15 values and the second sample has only 1:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
print "This is the result of the T-test:"
ttest = sm.stats.ttest_ind(np.array([821,823,814,815,816,817,881,891,234,354,678,765,989,435,657]), np.array([21]), alternative='larger')
print "pvalue:", ttest[1], ", at alpha = 0.05, thus the result is:", ttest[1] <= 0.05
```

Here's the result:

```
This is the result of the T-test:
pvalue: 2.72522964545e-08 , at alpha = 0.05, thus the result is: True
```

I am getting an answer saying that there is a significant difference between the two sample means.  Is this simply a bogus answer?

I was under the impression that one observation can't be assumed to belong to a normal distribution, so this assumption for a T-test itself can not be verified.  Thus the test should not be appropriate.

Comment: You can assume, sometimes with good reason, that both samples are normal variates with a common variance; but you can't check this assumption with these samples.

Comment: So, even if this assumption is made, is there any purpose to using such a T Test when a sample has only one observation anyway?  I feel like it doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: It tells you exactly the same thing as when the sample has many observations: the probability under the null hypothesis of equal means that the t-statistic would exceed that observed. Of course its power will be lower.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every realization comes from some distribution -there is nothing special with the case of one observation. It may very well come from a normal distribution.

The possible issue with the case of one observation, would be "how do we calculate the *sample* variance?" Obviously, the sample variance is zero (if calculated without the bias-correction factor), and an indeterminate form $0/0$ if we try to calculate it using the bias-correction factor
The t-statistic for the equality of means between two samples of unequal sizes and different sample variances ("[Welch's t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_or_Unequal_sample_sizes.2C_unequal_variances)"), is

$$t = {\overline{X}_1 - \overline{X}_2 \over s_{\overline{X}_1 - \overline{X}_2}},\qquad s_{\overline{X}_1 - \overline{X}_2} = \sqrt{{s_1^2 \over n_1} + {s_2^2  \over n_2}}$$

$s_1^2, s_2^2$ should be the sample variance expressions with the bias-correction factor, and so there should be a problem. Also the calculation for the appropriate degrees of freedom involves the magnitude "sample size minus one". So normally, the code should not result -but you have to find out exactly *which* "t-test" the software runs -there are many. In some of them the t-statistics can be calculated even when one of the samples is of size one.

Comment: Aha!  I believe I was using the wrong t-test.  I have included `usevar="unequal"` and now have a Welch's t-test on my hands.  Thanks!

Comment: And does the test result, even though theoretically it should not?

Comment: One I included the `usevar="unequal"` option which gave me a Welch's t-test, the result was in line with what we theoretically expected.

Comment: A comforting thing to know.